# Value limitation and type inference

Tags: types, f#

I built a simple function that, given a list, returns a list where the contiguous occurrences of an elements in the input are reduced to one.

```
let rec reduce l =
match l with
| []                ->  []
| [x]               ->  [x]
| x::(y::_ as xs)   ->  if x = y then
                            reduce xs
                        else
                            x::(reduce xs)


# reduce [1;1;2;2;2;3;3;4;3;3;3];;
- : int list = [1;2;3;4;3].
# reduce [’a’;’a’;’a’;’b’];;
- : char list = [’a’; ’b’].
# reduce [];;                // The case 
- : ’a list = []
```

Everything work as expected, except for the empty list `[]` input. The complainer says **error FS0030: Value restriction.** I tried to get a better comprehension of the phenomena through the [documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/), but I feel like I still do not possess the skills to get the point properly. Why a generic function does need the case with `[]` to be type specified? Could not the result `[]` being simply reported without type inference? And, finally, how the function should be structured, in order to menage such a case?

Comment: The problem is that `[]` is a `'a list` but the compiler needs to figure out what `'a` is and can't

Comment: Thank you @JohnPalmer for your contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John said in the comment, the problem is that `[]` does not give the compiler any hint about what the type of the list is - in all other cases, you know it's a list of characters of integers, but here, the type is not known.

You cannot run F# code that involves unknown generic types, so there is no way to run your code and get a generic list back - when running code, all types need to be fully specified.

You can provide a type annotation in a number of ways to fix the type:

```
reduce ([] : int list)
(reduce [] : int list)
(reduce:int list -> _) []
```

You could also wrap the call into another generic function, which compiles, because now the generic code is inside another generic function that requires a type in order to be used:

```
let foo () = reduce []
```

But now you have the same problem - you need to specify type when calling `foo`, or the compiler needs to be able to infer it from context, e.g. if you write `1 :: foo()`

Comment: Thank you Tomas. Because of your straightforward explanation, now I surely have a better comprehension of the issue.